# How can I check these equations if they have a solution?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratics, cubics

I have two equations which are: $p^3+k\equiv0 (mod \quad h) $ and $(3p^2+3mp+m^2)m\equiv 0(mod \quad h)$
where $k,h,m >0$ and $p\ge0$ and $h\nmid m$

I need to show for given k,m,h and for all $p\ge 0$ there is no solution for both equation at same time.  i.e. when I try by programatically for  k=5 and m=1 there isn't any solution for all $p\ge0$

$p^3+5\equiv0 (mod \quad 2) $ and $(3p^2+3p+1)\equiv 0(mod \quad 2)$

is there any way to show this?

edit : when h is prime I guess we can check by euler criterion checking $((3mp)^2-12m^2)^{\frac{h-1}2}$ if it is equvilant to -1 for mod h, there is no solution for this equation. if it is true what do we do when h is not prime?

Comment: You might need to impose some additional constraints on $k$, $m$ and $h$; otherwise those two equations can have solution simultaneously easily; e.g. if $h$ divides $m$.

Comment: @PeterKošinár ok I edited the question now thanks for your comment

Comment: $k = 6, h = 7, p = m = 2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I dont understand what you mean

Comment: @HTehlike: $2^3+6=14\equiv 0\,(\mod 7)$ and $(3\cdot 2^2 + 3\cdot 2\cdot 2 + 2^2)\cdot 2 = 28 \equiv 0\,(\mod 7)$ where $6,7,2 > 0$ and $2\ge 0$ and $7\nmid 2$.

Comment: @celtschk I know for some k and m there are solutions but for some k and m there isnt. I want to check this without trying all p

Comment: Ah, so your *actual* question is: For which values of $k$ and $m$ are there no solutions?

Comment: @celtschk yes indeed. actually my bad, I edited the title

Comment: Related [question on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/73884/53820).